# Can MVC 5 scaffolding not add selectlist for many-many relations? (Add Scaffold - MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to be able to use the **"Add - Scaffold"** in Visual Studio 2013 to add CRUD for a model that has a many-many relation with another model. Unfortunately the scaffolded view/controller doesn't touch the relation at all, no SelectList is rendered in the create/edit views.

The Scaffold works fine for one-to-many relations though. Is many-to-many a feature that is not implemented in the Scaffold tool, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Fluent API.

These are my models (stripped for readability)

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Iso { get; set; }

    public string GlobalName { get; set; }
    public string LocalName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

These are the Fluent API configuration classes

```
public class CategoryConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => new { c.Id });

        HasMany(c => c.Countries)
            .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("CategoryCountry_JT");
                m.MapLeftKey("CategoryId");
                m.MapRightKey("CountryId");
            });
    }
}

public class CountryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public CountryConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => new { c.Iso });

        Property(c => c.GlobalName).IsRequired();
        Property(c => c.LocalName).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Perhaps the Join Table has to declared as a real model instead of through `.Map(m => ...` for the Scaffold to work?

Comment: I would appreciate if you answer my question too: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567537/why-add-scaffold-does-not-appear-by-right-clicking-on-controllers-folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the built in Scaffold feature does not support many-many relations.

There is a [pretty good blog post about it here on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2013/09/20/managing-entity-relationships-with-mvc-scaffolding.aspx), it contains a usable solution.